# how make include to array my method

Tags: c#, arrays, function, methods

I want make some array with include my method as member ? 
i try that with this code and fint out red line. how to make it?

```
List<Action> a= new List<Action>();
 a.AddRange(getA1,getAll_LRDe,getAll_RL);
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: So you want to make a list of delegates?

Comment: that's right. it has been answered in answer 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use object initializer:

```
List<Action> a = new List<Action> { getA1, getAll_LRDe, getAll_RL };
```

Or pass an enumeration (array, list etc) as the argument of the `AddRange`:

```
List<Action> a = new List<Action>();
a.AddRange(new Action[] { getA1, getAll_LRDe, getAll_RL });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extensions method like this:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this List<T> list, params T[] items)
    {
        list.AddRange(items);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
a.AddRange(getA1,getAll_LRDe,getAll_RL);
```

Will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`AddRange` takes an `IEnumerable<Action>`:

```
a.AddRange(new Action[] { getA1,getAll_LRDe,getAll_RL });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `AddRange` you can use the object initializer

```
  var a = new List<Action> { getA1, getAll_LRDe, getAll_RL };
```

or the method `Add`

```
   a.Add(getA1);
   a.Add(getAll_LRDe);
   a.Add(getAll_RL);
```

If your goal is to put methods together and raise them, you could perhaps take an `event`.

```
   // create event in class
   public event Action MyEvent;

   // add delegates in constructor
   MyEvent += getA1;
   MyEvent += getAll_LRDe;
   MyEvent += getAll_RL;

   // execute all methods
   if (MyEvent != null)
       MyEvent();
```